# Xcode Saving To Plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

hi i have set up a table view to display entires in a plist and have a section to add new data to the plist but i am unable to save the data... it stores fine and display fine but when i leave the app and reload the new data has gone here is how im saving

```
- (IBAction) save: (id) sender {
NSLog(@"%@", @"Save pressed!");

if (self.job != nil) {
    // We're working with an existing drink, so let's remove
    // it from the array and just recreate it like we would a new
    // drink...
    [jobArray_ removeObject:self.job];
    self.job = nil; // This will release our reference and set the property to nil
}

// Create a new drink dictionary for the new values
NSMutableDictionary *newDrink = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newDrink setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:NAME_KEY];
[newDrink setValue:self.ingredientsTextView.text forKey:INGREDIENTS_KEY];
[newDrink setValue:self.directionsTextView.text forKey:DIRECTIONS_KEY];

// Add it to the master drink array and release our reference
[jobArray_ addObject:newDrink];

// Sort the array since we just added a new drink
NSSortDescriptor *nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:NAME_KEY ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[jobArray_ sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSorter]];

// Pop the modal view and go back to the list
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

am i making a mistake for it not to save to the plist? it loads the data i preset in the plist but not the new entrys

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please save the data in pList like this :

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myplist.plist"];

    NSLog(@"File path = %@", plistPath);

    NSFileManager *fileManager  =   [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath];

    // This line saves the dictionary to pList
    [dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: how would i add this to my current code to save the three values

Comment: Its already present in dictionary just add last line to it...get the path of your plist by given name in my code and write last line as mentioned in my code

Comment: should i add the line like this     [newDrink writeToFile:@"JobDirections.plist" atomically:YES];

Comment: could i send you the project to chekc it out?

Comment: i have emailed you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230110/ios-copy-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-directory